# Making 1-50 from 2016

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

> Make the numbers 1-50 using the numbers 2 0 1 6 in the given order.

1.You must use all four digits.

2.You may not use any other numbers.

3.You may use +, -, x, ÷, square root, squaring and cubing, exponentiation, parentheses, brackets, or other grouping symbols.

Comment: What operations are allowed?

Comment: All operations are allowed

Comment: Can you form two-digit numbers, e.g. `20+16=36`? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Matsmath I've editted it

Comment: In [an earlier revision](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/42385/3) of the question, you said raising to the powers of 2 and 3 was allowed. Is this still allowed, even though 3 isn't one of the four digits provided?

Comment: @NotVeryGood Are we allowed to use the given digits twice?

Comment: @randal'thor yes its allowed

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate from [this codegolf question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70361/official-dyalog-apl-2016-year-game)?

Comment: Are we allowed to use module (`%`), or (`|`), and (`&`), xor (`~`), byte-shifts (`>>` and `<<`), etc., since you state all operations are allowed?

Comment: is factorial allowed?

Answer (score 12):

Here's the complete list from 1 to 50. Some of them can be done in a 'pure' way, with no numbers appearing in the expression except the four specified. Others require squaring or cubing (which [the OP said](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42385/making-1-50-from-2016#comment126385_42385) is permitted), and I've marked these as such.

1. $2*0+1^6$
2. $2+0*16$
3. $2+0+1^6$
4. $20-16$
5. $2*0-1+6$
6. $2*0*1+6$
7. $2*0+1+6$
8. $2+0*1+6$
9. $2+0+1+6$
10. $2*(0-1+6)$
11. Needs squaring/cubing: $2^2+0+1+6$
12. $2*(0*1+6)$
13. $20-1-6$
14. $20*1-6$
15. $20+1-6$
16. $2*0+16$
17. $2^0+16$
18. $2+0+16$
19. $20-1^6$
20. $20/1^6$
21. $20+1^6$
22. $20+\sqrt{\sqrt{16}}$ (thanks @MariaDeleva)
23. Needs squaring/cubing: $-2+0+(-1+6)^2$
24. $20+\sqrt{16}$
25. $20-1+6$
26. $20*1+6$
27. $20+1+6$
28. Needs squaring/cubing: $-2^3+0*1+6^2$
29. Needs squaring/cubing: $-2^3+0+1+6^2$
30. Needs squaring/cubing: $(2^2+0+1)*6$
31. Needs squaring/cubing: $-2^2+0-1+6^2$
32. $(2+0)*16$
33. Needs squaring/cubing: $-2^2-0+1+6^2$
34. Needs squaring/cubing: $-2+0*1+6^2$
35. Needs squaring/cubing: $-2-0+1+6^2$
36. $20+16$
37. Needs squaring/cubing: $2-0-1+6^2$
38. Needs squaring/cubing: $2+0*1+6^2$
39. Needs squaring/cubing: $2+0+1+6^2$
40. $20*\sqrt{\sqrt{16}}$
41. Needs squaring/cubing: $2^2+0+1+6^2$
42. Needs squaring/cubing: $(2^3-0-1)*6$
43. Needs squaring/cubing: $2^3-0-1+6^2$
44. Needs squaring/cubing: $2^3+0*1+6^2$
45. Needs squaring/cubing: $2^3+0+1+6^2$
46. Needs factorial? $2^3+0!+1+6^2$ (thanks @numberknot)
47. Needs squaring/cubing: $-2-0+(1+6)^2$
48. Needs squaring/cubing: $(2^3+0*1)*6$
49. Needs squaring/cubing: $2*0+(1+6)^2$
50. Needs squaring/cubing: $(2+0)*(-1+6)^2$

Comment: That was quick, even if you only got half!

Comment: Thank you for these even if its only half ^3^

Comment: 46=2^3+0!+1+6^2

Comment: @numberknot Is factorial allowed? It's not one of the operations mentioned in the question.

Comment: @NotVeryGood The list is complete! :-)

Comment: I'm still hoping to find some way to make 46 without factorial.

Comment: @randal'thor 11 can easily be done without square/cube. 2*6-1+0=11

Comment: @dcfyj No, because 2,0,1,6 have to appear in the right order.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 4):

1. $2 * 0 + 1 ^ 6$
2. $2 + 0 * 1 * 6$
3. $2 + 0 + 1 ^ 6$
4. $20 - 16$
5. $2 * 0 + 1 - 6$
6. $2 * 0 * 1 + 6$
7. $2 * 0 + 1 + 6$
8. $2 + 0 * 1 + 6$
9. $2 + 0 + 1 + 6$
10. $2 * (0 - 1 + 6)$
11. $2 ^ 2 + 0 + 1 + 6$
12. $(2 + (0 * 1)) * 6$
13. $20 - 1 - 6$
14. $20 - 1*6$
15. $20 + 1 - 6$
16. $2 * 0 + 16$
17. $2 ^ 0 + 16$
18. $(2 + 0 + 1) * 6$
19. $20 - (1 ^ 6)$
20. $20/1 ^ 6$
21. $20 + 1 ^ 6$
22. $20 + \sqrt{\sqrt{16}}$ (Credits [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva))
23. $-2 + 0 + (-1 + 6)^2$
24. $20 + \sqrt{16}$
25. $20 - 1 + 6$
26. $20 + 1 * 6$
27. $20 + 1 + 6$
28. $(2 ^ 2 + 0) * (1 + 6)$
29. $-(2 ^ 3) + 0 + 1 + 6 ^ 2$
30. $(2 ^ 2 + 0 + 1) * 6$
31. $(2 ^ 2 + 0 + 1)^2 + 6$
32. $(2 + 0) * 16$
33. $-(2 + 0 + 1) + 6 ^ 2$
34. $-2 + 0 * 1 + 6 ^ 2$
35. $2 * 0 - 1 + 6 ^ 2$
36. $20 + 16$
37. $2 + 0 - 1 + 6 ^ 2$
38. $2 + 0 * 1 + 6 ^ 2$
39. $2 + 0 + 1 + 6 ^ 2$
40. $20 * \sqrt{\sqrt{16}}$
41. $2 ^ 2 + 0 + 1 + 6 ^ 2$
42. $(2 ^ 3 + 0 - 1) * 6$
43. $2 ^ 3 + 0 - 1 + 6 ^ 2$
44. $2 ^ 3 + 0 * 1 + 6 ^ 2$
45. $2 ^ 3 + 0 + 1 + 6 ^ 2$
46. 
47. $-2 + 0 + (1 + 6)^2$
48. $(2 ^ 3 + 0 * 1) * 6$
49. $(2 + 0 - 1 + 6) ^ 2$
50. $2^0 + (1 + 6)^2$

Comment: dude you used digit 3 ..in some of your equation

Comment: @numberknot Check the comments

Comment: exponents larger than 3 are not allowed according to the comments

Answer (score 2):

Some of these become possible with decimal point:
$$\begin{matrix}
11=.2^{0-1}+6 \\
30=.2^{0-1}*6 \\
35=\dfrac{20+1}{.6} \\
50=\dfrac{20}{1-.6}
\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

$17 = (2*0)!+16$

$18 = 2+0+16$

$18 = (2+0+1)*6$

$19 = 2+0!+16$

$20 = (2+0!+1)!/6$

$21 = (2+0!)(1+6)$

$22 = (2+0!)!+16$

$23 = 2^3-0!+16$

$24 = (2+0!+1)*6$

$25 = (2-0-1-6)^2$

You should be able to continue on your own.

Comment: what's the actual pattern that allows us to continue on our own?

Comment: When I answered the question it was different. I was just giving a little hint since he had just gotten stuck at #17. I stopped because it's his homework and it's tedious work.