# Make numbers 1 - 32 using the digits 2, 0, 1, 7

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

This is similar to the ["Four fours"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours) puzzle, but using the digits 2, 0, 1 and 7.

Rules:

- Use all four digits exactly once
- Allowed operations: +, -, x, ÷, ! (factorial), exponentiation, square root
- Parentheses and grouping (e.g. "21") are also allowed
- Squaring uses the digit 2 so expressions using multiple twos, like $2^2$ or $1^2 + 7^2$, are not allowed
- Keep the order "2017" in at least 16 expressions (and more if you can!)

Good luck and Happy New Year!

---

<sup>Similar question for [2016](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42385/making-1-50-from-2016)</sup>

Comment: is modulus operator allowed?

Comment: @Sid No, the modulus operator is not allowed.

Comment: Does the fourth rule also apply to "square rooting", because the square root works more or less the same

Comment: @FearsomeStatue no, it does not apply. You can use the square root any number of times (even though I don't see how that would help you...). It is possible to solve all numbers without using square root at all :-)

Comment: can we round, for example 120/7 -> 17?

Comment: @ev3commander No, rounding is not allowed.

Comment: Is grouping after some operations allowed (like "2+0!"=21) and is negating allow (e.g. -7+(2*0-1); the -1 is a subtraction, but the -7 at the start is a negation; sometimes helpful for maintaining 2017, both for the starting digit and if you want to negate the entire expression for the sake of having fun going into the negatives in the expression).

Comment: @JakobPampBengtsson No, grouping after some operations or any "string" operations are not allowed. Negation is allowed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This answer has 29 expressions with the "2017" order. Those NOT in order are denoted by sadness - :(

> $1=2*0+1^7$ 
> $2=2^0+1^7$
> $3=2+0+1^7$
> $4=-2+0-1+7$
> $5=-2+(0*1)+7$
> $6=(2*0)-1+7$
> $7=2^0-1+7$
> $8=(2*0)+1+7$
> $9=2+(0*1)+7$
> $10=2+0+1+7$
> $11=2+0!+1+7$
> $12=(2+0)*(-1+7)$
> $13=(2+0+1)!+7$
> $14=(2+0!)!+1+7$
> $15=-2+0+17$ (Improved for order by Ivo Beckers)
> $16=-((2*0)!)+17$
> $17=(2*0)+17$
> $18=(2^0)+17$
> $19=2+0+17$
> $20=2+0!+17$
> $21=20+1^7$
> $22=-2+ (\sqrt{-(0!-17)})!$ (Improved by Pratheek B!) 
> $23=(2+0!)!+17$
> $24=(2+0!)*(1+7)$
> $25=(7-1-0!)^2$ :(
> $26=20-1+7$
> $27=20+(1*7)$
> $28=20+1+7$
> $29=27+(1+0!)$ :(
> $30=10\sqrt{2+7}$ :(
> $31=(2+0!+1)!+7$
> $32=2^{-(0!)-1+7}$

FOOLING AROUND (I'm simply curious about how far we can go)

> $33=17*2-0!$
> $34 = (2+0)*17$ :D
> $35=((2+0!)!-1)*7$ (Improved by Christoph!)
> $36=(7-1+0)^2$
> $37=20+17$ :D
> $38=???$
> $39=7^2-10$
> $40=???$
> $41=(2+0!)!*7-1$

Comment: Why the sad faces?

Comment: @Deusovi, out of order. 15 also needs one.

Comment: -2 + 0 + 17 to make 15 in order

Comment: Very nice and very fast! Beats my number of solutions in order. And good job expanding the limit!

Comment: 38 equals what now?

Comment: See @PratheekB for an in-order solution to 22

Comment: @Neil W I'M SORRY I WAS REALLY TIRED ;-;

Comment: Well that's okay then.... :)

Comment: `Parentheses and grouping (e.g. "21") are also allowed` So, (2+0!) grouped with (1+7)? making 38? Would that be allowed? or you can't group 'results'?

Comment: I don't think that type of concatenation is allowed. "Grouping" likely refers to the direct concatenation of two integers.

Comment: You are right, I just read it in the comments :(

Answer (score 6):

In order solution for 22:

> $-2 + \sqrt{-0! + 17}! $

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I know there's another answer but I'm posting mine before I look at it (honest!). 28/32 in order.

> 1 = 2^(0*1*7)
>  2 = 2 + 0*1*7
>  3 = 2 + 0 + 1^7
>  4 = -2 + 0 - 1 + 7
>  5 = -2 + 0*1 + 7
>  6 = -2 + 0 + 1 + 7
>  7 = 2*0*1 + 7
>  8 = (2^0)*1 + 7
>  9 = 2 + 0*1 + 7
>  10 = 2 + 0 + 1 + 7
>  11 = 2 + 0! + 1 + 7
>  12 = 2*(0 - 1 + 7)
>  13 = (2 + 0 + 1)! + 7
>  14 = 2*(0*1 + 7)
>  15 = -2 + 0 + 17
>  16 = 2*(0 + 1 + 7)
>  17 = 2*0 + 17
>  18 = 2^0 + 17
>  19 = 2 + 0 + 17
>  20 = 20 * 1^7
>  21 = 20 + 1^7
>  *22 = 21 + 7^0
>  23 = (2 + 0!)! + 17
>  24 = (2 + 0!) * (1 + 7)
>  *25 = (7 - 2)^(0! + 1!)
>  26 = 20 - 1 + 7
>  27 = 20 + 1*7
>  28 = 20 + 1 + 7
>  *29 = 21 + 0! + 7
>  *30 = 210 / 7
>  31 = (2 + 0! + 1)! + 7
>  32 = 2 * (-0! + 17)

My attempts to press on...

> *33 = 2*17 - 0!
>  34 = (2 + 0)*17
>  35 = ((2 + 0!)! - 1)*7
>  36 = 2 * (0! + 17)
>  37 = 20 + 17
>  38 = ?
>  *39 = 7^2 - 10
>  40 = ?
>  *41 = ((2 + 0!)! * 7) - 1
>  42 = (2 + 0!)! *1*7
>  *43 = ((2 + 0!)! * 7) + 1
>  44 = ?
>  45 = ?
>  46 = ?
>  *47 = 7^2 - 0! - 1
>  48 = (2 + 0!)! * (1 + 7)
>  49 = ((2 + 0!)! + 1) * 7
>  *50 = 7^2 + 0 + 1
>  51 = (2 + 0!) * 17

Comment: well, you know, great minds and all that...

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for an elegant solution to this problem using octal (base-8) arithmetic. Perhaps someone could help me complete this. There's one I couldn't get the numbers in the right order, and another that I couldn't find any solution. Here's what I've got so far:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, with 29 in order: (I'm working on 25, 29, and 30)

> $ 1 = 2 * 0 + 1 ^ 7 $
> $ 2 = 2 + 0 * 1 * 7 $
> $ 3 = 2 + 0 + 1 ^ 7 $
> $ 4 = -2 + 0 - 1 + 7 $
> $ 5 = -2 + 0 + 1 * 7 $
> $ 6 = -2 + 0 + 1 + 7 $
> $ 7 = 2 * 0 * 1 + 7 $
> $ 8 = 2 + 0 - 1 + 7 $
> $ 9 = 2 + 0 + 1 * 7 $
> $ 10 = 2 + 0 + 1 + 7 $
> $ 11 = 2 + 0! + 1 + 7 $
> $ 12 = 2 * (0 - 1 + 7) $
> $ 13 = (2 + 0 + 1)! + 7 $
> $ 14 = (2 + 0 * 1) * 7 $
> $ 15 = -2 + 0 + 17 $
> $ 16 = (2 + 0) * (1 + 7) $
> $ 17 = 2 * 0 + 17 $
> $ 18 = 2 ^ 0 + 17 $
> $ 19 = 2 * 0! + 17 $
> $ 20 = 2 + 0! + 17 $
> $ 21 = (2 + 0 + 1) * 7 $
> $ 22 = -2 + \sqrt{-0! + 17}! $ (Thanks @PratheekB!)
> $ 23 = (2 + 0!)! + 17 $
> $ 24 = (2 + 0!) * (1 + 7) $
> $ 25 = (7 - 2) ^ {1 + 0!} $
> $ 26 = 20 - 1 + 7 $
> $ 27 = 20 * 1 + 7 $
> $ 28 = 20 + 1 + 7 $
> $ 29 = 27 + 0! + 1 $
> $ 30 = 210 \div 7 $
> $ 31 = (2 + 0! + 1)! + 7 $
> $ 32 = 2 * (-0! + 17) $

<sup>Besides 22, I came up with these by myself.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A bit cheeky with the use of a decimal point:

> (20+1)/.7 = 30

Or, using the same logic:

210/7 = 30

Answer (score 0):

Half answer(all in order)

> $1=(2*0*1*7)!$ 
>  $2=2+0*1*7$ 
>  $3=2+0+1^7$ 
>  $4=2+0!+1^7$ 
>  $5=(2+0!)!-1^7$ 
>  $6=(2+0+1^7)!$ 
>  $7=2*0*1+7$ 
>  $8=2*0+1+7$ 
>  $9=2-0!+1+7$ 
>  $10=2+0+1+7$ 
>  $11=2+0!+1+7$ 
>  $12=(2+0!)!-1+7$ 
>  $13=20-1*7$ 
>  $14=20+1-7$ 
>  $15=-2+0+17$ 
>  $16=-2+0!+17$ 
>  $17=2*0+17$ 
>  $18=2-0!+17$ 
>  $19=2+0+17$ 
>  $20=2+0!+17$ 
>  $21=(2+0+1)*7$ 
>  $22=-2+(\sqrt{-0!+17})!$ Thanks @Pratheek B 
>  $23=(2+0!)!+17$ 
>  $24=(2+0!+1^7)!$ 
>  $**25=(-0!-1+7)^2**$

Answer (score -1):

Possible in order solutions for 25 and 29:

> 2 + (-0! - 1 + 7) = 25
>  2 + (0! + 1 + 7) = 29

Or is that cheating?

Comment: "+" is addition, not concatenation. So yes, that's cheating.