# Make numbers 1 - 30 using the digits 2, 0, 1, 8

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

It's 2018 so let's repeat [last year's challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47409/make-numbers-1-32-using-the-digits-2-0-1-7) with new digits.

This is similar to the ["Four fours"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours) puzzle, but using the digits 2, 0, 1 and 8.

Rules:

- Use all four digits exactly once
- Allowed operations: +, -, x, ÷, ! (factorial), exponentiation, square root
- Parentheses and grouping (e.g. "21") are also allowed
- Squaring uses the digit 2 so expressions using multiple twos, like $2^2$ or $1^2 + 8^2$, are not allowed
- Keep the order "2 0 1 8" in at least 25 expressions (and more if you can!)
- The modulus operator is not allowed
- Rounding is not allowed (e.g. 201/8=25)

Good luck and Happy New Year!

---

<sup>Similar question for [2016](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42385/making-1-50-from-2016)</sup>

Comment: Can we use the unary - operator? (i.e. -2)

Comment: Could we get a special permission to also use the decimal point? Pretty please with perfect solutions and sugar on top? 8-]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Found 29 solutions with the numbers in order. Found two almost acceptable cheats for the remaining one.

> $30 = 21 + 0! + 8 = \frac{(2 + 0! + 1)!}{ .8 } = \sqrt{\frac{(2+0+1)!!}{.8}}$ (*Cheaty McCheatface*)
>  $29 = 20 + 1 + 8 $
>  $28 = 20 * 1 + 8 $
>  $27 = 20 -1 + 8$
>  $26 = 2 + \sqrt{\sqrt{(0! + 1)^8}} !$
>  $25 = \sqrt{\sqrt{((2 + 0!)!-1)^8}} $
>  $24 = (2+0!+1^8)!$
>  $23 = 20 + \sqrt{1+8}$
>  $22 = -2 + \sqrt{\sqrt{(0! + 1)^8}} !$
>  $21 = 20 + 1^8$
>  $20 = 20 * 1^8$
>  $19 = 20 - 1^8$
>  $18 = 2 * 0 + 18$
>  $17 = 20 - \sqrt{1+8}$
>  $16 = 2^{0!+\sqrt{1+8}}$
>  $15 = -2 - 0! + 18$
>  $14 = -(2 + 0) * (1 - 8)$
>  $13 = 20 + 1 -8 $
>  $12 = 20 * 1 - 8 $
>  $11 = 20 - 1 - 8 $
>  $10 = 2^0 + 1 + 8$
>  $9 = 2 * 0 + 1 + 8 $
>  $8 = 2 * 0 * 1 + 8 $
>  $7 = 2 * 0 - 1 + 8 $
>  $6 = (2 + 0) * \sqrt{1+8}$
>  $5 = -2 + 0 - 1 + 8$
>  $4 = 2 * (0! + 1^8)$
>  $3 = 2 + 0 + 1^8 $
>  $2 = 20 - 18$
>  $1 = 2 * 0 + 1^8$

Comment: Damn, those nested sqrts are absolutely brilliant.

Comment: @VotBear thanks! (spoiler: I didn't really actually calculate the fourth root of 390625, that's just "five squared" in masquerade)

Comment: @Bass I want to complete your list with 30 in order: "2(0!+1)"+8. We were allowed to group, so I grouped the 2 we got with a 2 I made and got 22. Then add 8 and we are done :)

Comment: @Tweakimp uearggh, that's so nasty. Certainly gets the job done within the rules as they are stated. Probably not within the rules as they were intended, but I agree, technically correct is the best kind of correct :-)

Comment: oooh, I thought that using a square root consumed the 2!

Comment: Very nice, congratulations! Did you try going beyond 30? I found solutions up to 42 (not in order), but couldn't find for 31 and 33 (without decimal points and string grouping ;-) ).

Comment: To create the solution for **30 in order** you can use double factorial: `((2 + 0!)!)!! - 18 = 6!! - 18 = 2·4·6 - 18 = 48 - 18 = 30`. Full credit goes to the smart mind EmNero from the [German math forum](https://www.mathelounge.de/504674/denk-challenge-erschaffe-die-zahlen-bis-mit-den-ziffern-und).

Comment: @KaiNoack Wow, thanks! Great find! I'm glad that the challenge is spreading around :-)

Comment: @KaiNoack Cool! Still, introducing an entirely new operator probably isn't much less of a crime than introducing the decimal point :-)

Comment: @ Tweakimp - "2(0! + 1)" + 8 is not valid.  That is not what is meant by grouping.  Grouping [the digits together] is concatenation.  Your expression

Comment: . . . is equal to 2(2) + 8 = 4 + 8 = 12.  Once what is inside the digits becomes simplified, it becomes a *number*, not a digit, to be used to multiply by the 2 to its left, which is taking on the role of a number at that point.

Answer (score 14):

Finished all 30, with only 4 not in order

> $1  = 2 ^{(0 * 1 * 8)}$
>  $2  = 2 + (0 * 1 * 8)$
>  $3  = 2 + 0 + (1 ^ 8)$
>  $4  = -2 - 0! - 1 + 8$
>  $5  = -2 + 0 - 1 + 8$
>  $6  = -2 + (0 * 1) + 8$
>  $7  = (2 * 0) - 1 + 8$
>  $8  = (2 * 0 * 1) + 8$
>  $9  = (2 * 0) + 1 + 8$
>  $10 = 2 + (0 * 1) + 8$
>  $11 = 2 + 0 + 1 + 8$
>  $12 = 2 + 0! + 1 + 8$
>  $13 = (2 + 0!)! - 1 + 8$
>  $14 = (2 + 0!)! + (1 * 8)$
>  $15 = (2 + 0!)! + 1 + 8$
>  $16 = 2 * (0 + (1 * 8))$
>  $17 = -2 + 0! + 18$
>  $18 = (2 + 0) * (1 + 8)$
>  $19 = 2 - 0! + 18$
>  $20 = 2 + 0 + 18$
>  $21 = (2 + 0!) * (-1 + 8)$
>  $22 =$
>  $23 = 20 + \sqrt{(1 + 8)}$
>  $24 = (2 + 0 + 1) * 8$
>  $25 = $
>  $26 = $
>  $27 = (2 + 0!) * (1 + 8)$
>  $28 = 20 + (1 * 8)$
>  $29 = 20 + 1 + 8$
>  $30 = $

Without maintaining the 2018 order:

> $22 = 21 + 8^0$
>  $25 = 8 * (2 + 0!) - 1$
>  $26 = 28 - 1 - 0!$
>  $30 = 21 + (0! + 8)$

Comment: You have the same calculation for 17 and 19.

Comment: @Thrax He propably intended to switch them like $0! - 2 + 18$, but that would break the rules.

Comment: My bad, my bad. And @ibrahimmahrir i intended it to be -2 + 0! + 18

Comment: 25: $((2+0!)-1)*8$

Comment: @OldBunny2800 That will result in (3-1)*8 = 16.

Comment: Oh whoops, my bad

Answer (score 5):

Belated Happy New Year!

Only uses addition, subtraction, multiplication, exponents and factorials! (and brackets):

> $$1=2-0!\cdot1^8$$
>   $$2=20-18$$
>   $$3=2+0+1^8$$
>   $$4=-2-0!-1+8$$
>   $$5=-2+0-1+8$$
>   $$6=-2+0!-1+8$$
>   $$7=-2+0+1+8$$
>   $$8=2-0!-1+8$$
>   $$9=2+0-1+8$$
>   $$10=2+0!-1+8$$
>   $$11=2+0+1+8$$
>   $$12=2+0!+1+8$$
>   $$13=20+1-8$$
>   $$14=(2+0+1)!+8$$
>   $$15=-2-0!+18$$
>   $$16=-2+0+18$$
>   $$17=-2+0!+18$$
>   $$18=2\cdot0+18$$
>   $$19=2-0!+18$$
>   $$20=2+0+18$$
>   $$21=2+0!+18$$
>   $$\color{red}{22=21+(0!)^8}$$
>   $$\color{red}{23=(2+0!)\cdot8-1}$$
>   $$24=(2+0+1)\cdot8$$
>   $$\color{red}{25=(2+0!)\cdot8+1}$$
>   $$\color{red}{26=28-0!-1}$$
>   $$27=20-1+8$$
>   $$28=20^1+8$$
>   $$29=20+1+8$$
>   $$\color{red}{30=21+0!+8}$$

Comment: Is 6 supposed to be 0!?

Comment: @Lefty What do you mean?

Comment: I'm seeing -2+0-1+8=6 - which is not true. But -2+0!-1+8=6. Maybe it's just a problem with the way the line is displayed...?

Comment: No problem. I also think 8 is wrong...?

Comment: 20=2+0+18, if you want to simplify

Comment: I'm flying now - 2=20-18

Comment: @Lefty Have reduced the use of exponents and products now :)

Answer (score 4):

Happy 2018! I hope everyone has a wonderful year!

I reached for only short and simple answers. I didn't use square roots.

> $1  = 2+0-1^8$
>  $2  = 20-18$
>  $3  = 2+0+1^8$
>  $4  = 2+0!+1^8$
>  $5  = -2+0-1+8$
>  $6  = -2+0*1-8$
>  $7  = 2*0-1+8$
>  $8  = 2*0*1+8$
>  $9  = 2*0+1+8$
>  $10 = 2+0*1+8$
>  $11 = 20-1-8$
>  $12 = 2+0!+1+8$
>  $13 = 20+1-8$
>  $14 = (2+0!)!*1+8$
>  $15 = (2+0!)!+1+8$
>  $16 = (2+0*1)*8$
>  $17 = -2^0+18$
>  $18 = 2*0+18$
>  $19 = 2^0+18$
>  $20 = 2+0+18$
>  $21 = 20+1^8$
>  * $22 = 21+(8*0)!$
>  * $23 = (2+0!)*8-1$
>  $24 = (2+0+1)*8$
>  * $25 = (2+0!)*8+1$
>  * $26 = -1-0!+28$
>  $27 = 20-1+8$
>  $28 = 20*1+8$
>  $29 = 20+1+8$
>  * $30 = 28+1+0!$

*The starred ones are out of order.*

Comment: The expressions for $4$, $5$ and $6$ are also not in order.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Great catch, thank you! I changed 4 to 2+0!+1^8, but the other two involved simply switching the middle numbers.
(Edit, no rep to comment on yours: very nice compression! I like how simple your answers are!)

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you don't mind my edits :)

Answer (score 3):

> $$1=2\cdot0+1^8$$
>   $$2=2-(0\cdot1)^8$$
>   $$3=2-0+1^8$$
>   $$4=2+0!+1^8$$
>   $$5=-2-0!\cdot1+8$$
>   $$6=-2-0\cdot1+8$$
>   $$7=-2-0+1+8$$
>   $$8=2\cdot0\cdot1+8$$
>   $$9=2\cdot0+1+8$$
>   $$10=2+0\cdot1+8$$
>   $$11=2+0+1+8$$
>   $$12=2+0!+1+8$$
>   $$13=(2+0!)!-1+8$$
>   $$14=(2+0!)!1+8$$ 
>   $$15=(2+0!)!+1+8$$
>   $$16=\sqrt{2^{0\cdot1+8}}$$
>   $$17=-2^0+18$$
>   $$18=(2+0!)!\sqrt{1+8}$$ 
>   $$19=20-1^8$$
>   $$20=20\cdot1^8$$
>   $$21=20+1^8$$
>   $$22=-2+\sqrt{\sqrt{(0!+1)^8}}!$$
>   $$23=20+\sqrt{1+8}$$
>   $$24=(2+0+1^8)!$$
>   $$25=\sqrt{\sqrt{((2+0!)!-1)^8}}$$
>   $$26=2+\sqrt{\sqrt{(0!+1)^8}}!$$
>   $$27=20-1+8$$
>   $$28=20\cdot1+8$$
>   $$29=20+1+8$$
>   $$^*30=28+1+0!$$

Comment: That's definitely the most hard working 18 I've seen here :-)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to solve these on my own and got everything but 25 and 30.  I got unique solutions for some of them.

> $1 = 2 + 0 - 1^8$
>  $2 = 20 - 18$
>  $3 = 2 + 0 + 1^8$
>  $4 = 2 + 0! + 1^8$
>  $5 = 2 + 0 + \sqrt{1+8}$
>  $6 = 2 + 0! + \sqrt{1+8}$
>  $7 = (2 * 0) - 1 + 8$
>  $8 = (2 - 0 - 1) * 8$
>  $9 = 2 + 0 - 1 + 8$
>  $10 = 2 + (0 * 1) + 8$
>  $11 = 20 - 1 - 8$
>  $12 = 20 * 1 - 8$
>  $13 = 20 + 1 - 8$
>  $14 = (2 + 0)(-1 + 8)$
>  $15 = (2! + 0!)! + 1 + 8$
>  $16 = (2 + 0 * 1) * 8$
>  $17 = 20 - \sqrt{1+8}$
>  $18 = (2 - 0!) * 18$
>  $19 = 20 - 1^8$
>  $20 = 2 + 0 + 18$
>  $21 = 20 + 1^8$
>  $22 = -2 + (0! + \sqrt{1+8})!$
>  $23 = 20 + \sqrt{1+8}$
>  $24 = (2! + 0!)! + 18$
>  $*25 = ((2 + 0!) * 8) + 1$
>  $26 = 20 + \sqrt{1+8}!$
>  $27 = 20 - 1 + 8$
>  $28 = 20 * 1 + 8$
>  $29 = 20 + 1 + 8$
>  $*30 = 21 + 0! + 8$

Comment: Well done on the 22 and 26 especially! Very pretty.