# Make numbers 1-30 using 2, 0, 1, 9

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-theory, calculation-puzzle

This is very similar to the [2, 0, 1, 8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58633/make-numbers-1-30-using-the-digits-2-0-1-8) problem. Just try to make all numbers 1-30 using the digits 2, 0, 1, 9.

Rules:

- Use all four digits exactly once
- Allowed operations: +, -, x, ÷, ! (factorial), exponentiation, square root
- Parentheses and concatenation are allowed (e.g. $20 + (1 * 9)$)
- Squaring uses the digit 2 so expressions using multiple twos, like 22 or $12+92$, are not allowed
- Keep the order "2 0 1 9" in all expressions
- The modulus operator is not allowed
- Rounding is not allowed (e.g. $201/9=22$)

Comment: but.. but... how could you? we are not in 2019 yet!

Comment: Is "0 1 9 2" still considered in to be in order?

Comment: @infinitezero no

Comment: If squaring uses the two, why would square root not use both the one and the two?

Comment: Just for fun, $(-2^{-(0!)})!^{-1+\sqrt9}=\pi$, if you use the gamma function for the factorial

Comment: Because you can write the square root without numbers: $x^\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{x}$. There's an extra symbol for that, that doesn't use numbers.

Comment: Just ask 1-2019 with 2,0,1,9 and next year, we can flag all of them as duplicates.

Comment: @PL457 Just ask Make numbers 1-30 using $w,x,y,z$.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 The gamma function of 0 is complex infinity, so you're using two different factorial functions in that definition.

Comment: [Solutions in Python](https://tio.run/##dVLRboQgEHznKzbpi4AmgHpK@jHGtDVHUsVyXJN@vQV6Clzsk8nMzjIz6/pjr3oR2zYZPcMwTHd7Nx/DAGpetbHwrr7VTekFBX4e7XVnpvHNaqPGzxJuX8aiFxDAgIPcOLzCatRiQbCKyxIEdV9CJBKRIYTRgNURow@oScYcRP3@QmLUPskP4nIQVXiLStQ97TjsFg8RRn2mol4lc5XzwlliL2zmPDfsEJEhfqaOSHyZ4T@yif0QwqsTa7zdRyIZdmOvv6T9VnsJvMvj@OIZSfh@5/0qTIJzmeV1F2J5xQ7J4zpA/JfNcXX04PWRP46FkWjSR89H2jTi2fFEUgI5n@jSvK46/wP2UUULf043JxPMl1KzFKCuxyJPiknhlWV2nGzgNNX2Cw)

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm using $z!=\Gamma(1+z)$, so $0!=\Gamma(1+0)=\Gamma(1)=1$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> $30 = 20 + 1 + 9$
>  $29 = 20^1 + 9$
>  $28 = 20 - 1 + 9$
>  $27 =( 2 + 0 + 1)* 9$
>  $26 = 2 + 0 + (1 + \sqrt{9})!$
>  $25 = 2^0 + (1 + \sqrt{9})!$
>  $24 = (2 + 0 - 1 + \sqrt{9})!$
>  $23 = -2^0 + (1 + \sqrt{9})!$
>  $22 = -2 + 0 + (1 + \sqrt{9})!$
>  $21 = 2 + 0 + 19$
>  $20 = (2 + 0)(1 + 9)$
>  $19 = 20 - 1^9$
>  $18 = 2^{(0+1)} * 9$
>  $17 = -2 + 0 + 19$
>  $16 = 20 - (1 + \sqrt{9})$
>  $15 = (2 + 0 + 1)! + 9$
>  $14 = 20^1 - (\sqrt{9})!$
>  $13 = 20 - 1 - (\sqrt{9})!$
>  $12 = 2 + 0 + 1 + 9$
>  $11 = 2^{(0 + 1)} + 9$
>  $10 = 2 + 0 - (1 - 9)$
>  $9 = (2 + 0 + 1)! + \sqrt{9}$
>  $8 = (2 + 0)(1 + \sqrt{9})$
>  $7 = -2^{(0 + 1)} + 9$
>  $6 = 2 + 0 + 1 + \sqrt{9}$
>  $5 = 2^0 + 1 + \sqrt{9}$
>  $4 = 2 + 0 - 1 + \sqrt{9}$
>  $3 = (2 + 0 - 1) * \sqrt{9}$
>  $2 = (2 + 0) * 1^9$
>  $1 = (2 - 0 - 1)^9$

Comment: There is also (2^0)*1*9 for nine

Answer (score 11):

> $1 = 20 - 19 $
>  $2 = 2 + 0 * 1 * 9$
>  $3 = 2 + 0 + 1^9$
>  $4 = 2 + 0! + 1^9$
>  $5 = (2 + 0!)! - 1^9$
>  $6 = (2 + 0 + 1^9)!$
>  $7 = (2 + 0!)! + 1^9$
>  $8 = 2 * 0 - 1 + 9$
>  $9 = 2 * 0 * 1 + 9$
>  $10 = 2 * 0 + 1 + 9$
>  $11 = 2 + 0 * 1 +9$
>  $12 = 2 * 0! + 1 + 9$
>  $13 = 2 * (0! + 1) + 9$
>  $14 = (2+0!)!-1+9$
>  $15 = (2+0!)!+1*9$
>  $16 = (2+0!)!+1+9$
>  $17 = 20-\sqrt{1*9}$
>  $18 = 2 * 0! * 1 *9$
>  $19 = 20 - 1^9$
>  $20 = 20 * 1^9$
>  $21 = 20 + 1^9$
>  $22 = 20 - 1 + \sqrt{9}$
>  $23 = 20 + \sqrt{1 * 9}$
>  $24 = (2 + 0! + 1^9)!$
>  $25 = 20 -1 + \sqrt{9}!$
>  $26 = 20 + \sqrt{1 * 9}!$
>  $27 = (2 + 0 + 1) * 9$
>  $28 = 20 - 1 + 9$
>  $29 = 20^1 + 9$
>  $30 = 20 + 1 + 9 $

Answer (score 3):

PARTIAL:

19:

> $2*0+19$

21:

> $2+0+19$

29:

> $20+1*9$

30:

> $20+1+9$

more incoming

Answer (score 3):

1. > 20 - 19 = 1
   > OR
   > SQRT(20 - 19) = 1
   > OR
   > (20 - 19)! = 1
2. > 2 + 0 * 19 = 2
   > OR
   > 20 / (1 + 9) = 2
3. > 2 + 0 + 1^9 = 3
4. > 2 * 0 + 1 + SQRT(9) = 4
5. > 2 + 0 * 1 + SQRT(9) = 5
6. > - 2 + 0 - 1 + 9 = 6
   > OR
   > 2 + 0 + 1 + SQRT(9) = 6
7. > - 2 + 0 * 1 + 9 = 7
   > OR
   >  (20 + 1) / SQRT(9) = 7
8. > 2 * 0 - 1 + 9 = 8
9. > 2 * 0 * 1 + 9 = 9
   > OR
   > 2^0 - 1 + 9 = 9
10. > 20 - 1 - 9 = 10
    > OR
    > 20 - (1 + 9) = 10
    > OR
    > 2 * 0 + 1 + 9 = 10
11. > 2 + 0 * 1 + 9 = 11
    > OR
    > 20^1 - 9 = 11
    > OR
    > 2 * 01 + 9 = 11
    > OR
    > 20 * 1 - 9 = 11
12. > 20 + 1 - 9 = 12
    > OR
    > 2 + 0 + 1 + 9 = 12
    > OR
    > 2 - 0 + 1 + 9 = 12
13. > 20 - 1 - (SQRT(9))! = 13
14. > 20 - 1 * (SQRT(9))! = 14
15. > 20 + 1 - (SQRT(9))! = 15
16. > 20 - 1 - SQRT(9) = 16
    > OR
    > 20 - (1 + SQRT(9)) = 16
17. > 20 - 1 * SQRT(9) = 17
18. > 20 + 1 - SQRT(9) = 18
    > OR
    > (2 + 0) * 1 * 9 = 18
    > OR
    > (2 + 0) / (1 / 9) = 18
19. > 2 * 0 + 19 = 19
20. > 2^0 + 19 = 20
21. > 2 + 0 + 19 = 21
22. > 20 - 1 + SQRT(9) = 22
23. > 20 * 1 + SQRT(9) = 23
24. > 20 + 1 + SQRT(9) = 24
25. > 20 - 1 + (SQRT(9))! = 25
26. > 20^1 + (SQRT(9))! = 26
27. > 20 + 1 + (SQRT(9))! = 27
28. > 20 - 1 + 9 = 28
29. > 20 * 1 + 9 = 29
30. > 20 + 1 + 9 = 30

Comment: I really like how you gave "or" options.  That said, you missed a few more that make 10.

Comment: The ORs were as I found them, and not intended to be a complete solution.  I have added a few for 10.

Answer (score 3):

00

> $2 * 0 * 1 * 9$

01

> $2 * 0 + 1^9$

02

> $2 + 0 * 1 * 9$

03

> $2 + 0 + 1 ^ 9$

04

> $2 * 0 + 1 + \sqrt{9}$

05

> $2 + 0 * 1 + \sqrt{9}$

06

> $2 + 0 + 1 + \sqrt{9}$

07

> $(20 + 1) / \sqrt{9}$

08

> $2 * 0 + ( -1 + 9)$

09

> $2 * 0 * 1 + 9$

10

> $2 * 0 + 1 + 9$

11

> $2 + 0 * 1 + 9$

12

> $2 + 0 + 1 + 9$

13

> $ 20 - 1 - \sqrt{9}!$

14

> 2$0 - 1 * \sqrt{9}!$

15

> $20 + 1 - \sqrt{9}!$

16

> $20 - 1 - \sqrt{9}$

17

> $-2 + 0 + 19$

18

> $-(2^0) + 19$

19

> $2 * 0 + 19$

20

> $2 ^ 0 + 19$

21

> $2 + 0 + 19$

22

> $20 - 1 + \sqrt{9}$

23

> $20 + 1 * \sqrt{9}$

24

> $20 + 1 + \sqrt{9}$

25

> $20 - 1 + \sqrt{9}!$

26

> $20 + 1 * \sqrt{9}!$

27

> $20 + 1 + \sqrt{9}!$

28

> $20 - 1 + 9$

29

> $ 20 + 1 * 9$

30

> $20 + 1 + 9$

Answer (score 2):

Full solution

> $20-19 = 1  $
>  $2 + 0 * 19 = 2 $
>  $2 * 0 * 1 + \sqrt{9} = 3 $
>  $2 * 0 + 1 + \sqrt{9} = 4$
>  $2 + 0 * 1 + \sqrt{9} = 5$
>  $-2 + 0 - 1 + 9 = 6$
>  $-2 + 0 * 1 + 9 = 7$
>  $2 * 0 - 1 + 9 = 8$
>  $2 * 0 * 1 + 9 = 9$
>  $20 - 1 - 9 = 10$
>  $20^1 - 9 = 11$
>  $20 + 1 - 9 = 12$
>  $20 - 1 - (\sqrt{9})! = 13$
>  $2 * (0 + 1 + (\sqrt{9})! = 14$
>  $(2 + 0 + 1)! + 9 = 15$
>  $2 * (0 - 1 + 9) = 16$
>  $-2 + 0 + 19 = 17$
>  $-2^0 + 19 = 18$
>  $2 * 0 + 19 = 19$
>  $20! / 19! = 20$
>  $2 + 0 + 19 = 21$
>  $20 - 1 + \sqrt{9} = 22$
>  $20 * 1 + \sqrt{9} = 23$
>  $20 + 1 + \sqrt{9} = 24$
>  $20 - 1 + (\sqrt{9})! = 25$
>  $20 + 1 * (\sqrt{9})! = 26$
>  $(2 + 0 + 1) * 9 = 27$
>  $20 - 1 + 9 = 28$
>  $20 ^1 + 9 = 29$
>  $20 + 1 + 9 = 30$

Answer (score 2):

Here they are, as simple and neat as I could make them!

$1-6:$

> $$\small\begin{array}{c|c}1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline2\cdot0+1^9&2+0\cdot1\cdot9&2\cdot0\cdot1+\sqrt9&2+0!+1^9&-2-0!-1+9&-2+0-1+9\end{array}$$

$7-12:$

> $$\small\begin{array}{c|c}7&8&9&10&11&12\\\hline-2+0\cdot1+9&-2+0+1+9&2\cdot0\cdot1+9&2+0-1+9&2+0\cdot1+9&2+0+1+9\end{array}$$

$13-18:$

> $$\small\begin{array}{c|c}13&14&15&16&17&18\\\hline2+0!+1+9&(2+0!)!-1+9&20+1-\sqrt9!&(2+0!)!+1+9&-2+0+19&2\cdot(0+1)\cdot9\end{array}$$

$19-25:$

> $$\small\begin{array}{c|c}19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\\hline2\cdot0+19&2^0+19&20+1^9&2+0!+19&20\cdot1+\sqrt9&20+1+\sqrt9&(2+0!)!+19\end{array}$$

$26-30:$

> $$\small\begin{array}{c|c}26&27&28&29&30\\\hline20+1\cdot\sqrt9!&20+1+\sqrt9!&20-1+9&20\cdot1+9&20+1+9\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

1

> $20-19$

2

> $2+(0*19)$

3

> $(2*0*1)+√9$

4

> $(2*0)+√(9)+1$

5

> $2+(0*1)+√(9)$

6

> $2+0+1+√(9)$

7

> $-2+0+(1*9)$

8

> $(2*0)-1+9$

9

> $(2*0*1)+9$

10

> $(2*0)+1+9$

11

> $2+(0*1)+9$

12

> $2+0+1+9$

13

> $20-1-(√9)!$

14

> $20*1-(√9)!$

15

> $(2+0+1)!+9$

16

> $2^(0+1+√9)$

17

> $20-(1*√9)$

18

> $(2+0*1)*9$

19

> $(2*0)+19$

20

> $(2^0)+19$

21

> $2+0+19$

22

> $20-1+√9$

23

> $(20*1)+√9$

24

> $20+1+√9$

25

> $20-1+(√9)!$

26

> $(20*1)+(√9)!$

27

> $(2+0+1)*9$

28

> $20-1+9$

29

> $(20*1)+9$

30

> $20+1+9$

Answer (score 2):

- 1= ((2 + 0 + 1) / √9)!
- 2= 2 + 0 * 1 * 9
- 3 = 2 + (0 * 1 * 9)!
- 4 = 2^(0 - 1 + √9)
- 5 = 2 + 0 * 1 + √9
- 6 = -(2 + 0 + 1) + 9
- 7 = -2 + 0 * 1 + 9
- 8 = -2 + 0 + 1 + 9
- 9 = 2 * 0 * 1 + 9
- 10 = 2 * 0 + 1 + 9
- 11 = 2 + 0 * 1 + 9
- 12 = 2 + 0 + 1 + 9
- 13 = 2 + 0! + 1 + 9
- 14 = 2 * -(0! + 1 - 9)
- 15 = (2 + 0 + 1)! + 9
- 16 = -2 + (0! + 1) * 9
- 17 = -2 + 0 + 19
- 18 = 2 * (0 * 1 + 9)
- 19 = 2 * 0 + 19
- 20 = 20 * 1^9
- 21 = 20 + 1^9
- 22 = 20 - 1 + √9
- 23 = 20 * 1 + √9
- 24 = 20 + 1 + √9

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Please use spoilers '>!'  to hide your answer. Happy puzzling = )

Answer (score 2):

### Solutions for 25-36

- > 25 = 2 - 0! + (1 + √9)!
- > 26 = 2 + 0 + (1 + √9)!
- > 27 = (2 + 0 + 1) * 9
- > 28 = 20 - 1 + 9
- > 29 = 20 + 1 * 9
- > 30 = 20 + 1 + 9
- > 31 = 2 || 0! + 1 + 9
- > 32 = 2 ^ (0! + 1 + √9)
- > 33 = (2 - 0!) || 1 * √9
- > 34 = 2 || 0! + 1 || √9
- > 35 = **—not here yet—**
- > 36 = (2 + 0!)! ^ (-1 + 9)

Comment: I believe you should merge this into your previous answer of solutions from 1-24, but nice answer nevertheless.